# Regex to replace digits with a character x times the match's length

Tags: javascript, regex

Got the regex `(?<!a|\d)[0-9]{6,}` to match any digits with 6 in length or more, but that do not start with \ or digits.

Previously, I used I used `[0-9]` in `replace("[0-9]", "x")`, and it would replace `111` with `xxx`.

But now with the new formula `replace("(?<!a|\d)[0-9]{6,}", "x")` it just replaces with one `x`.

How can I make it so it continues the old behavior? I tried to use a function but it did not seem to work very well (using Zoho mail which uses weird JS language)

Comment: This code is not valid. Please check spelling (test code). Best include a runnable snippet that demonstrates the isssue (the toolbar has a button for it)

Comment: @trincot Weird, here: https://jsfiddle.net/rduyjg1q/

Comment: Yes, that fiddle produces the expected error "replaceall is not defined"

Comment: Oh, right, sorry, I just remembered replaceall is platform specific, so I mean replace

Comment: Did you try? Please edit your question and include inside the question a runnable snippet with all the code that is needed to reproduce your issue. Use the toolbar to insert a snippet. NB: `replaceall` is wrong -- not related to any platform.

Comment: This is what I use: https://www.zoho.com/deluge/help/functions/string/replaceall.html so the js is apparently different from regular js

Comment: Like I said in my first comment. Spelling is important. Different spelling, and different prefix. Please update your question.

Comment: my bad, updated

Comment: Still not good. Did you test the code you posted as-is? Please insert a runnable snippet into your question and you'll be able to test before you post your question...

Answer (score 2):

Use a function as the replacement. It can then repeat the character the same number of times as the length of the match.

```js
console.log('123456'.replace(/(?<!a|\d)[0-9]{6,}/g, match => "x".repeat(match.length)));
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar. Sorry, I edited my message a minute later since I tried a function earlier and it did not seem to work. Either because the platform does not support it or maybe I did something wrong: https://i.imgur.com/KhQ0ab4.png

Comment: This isn't the reason for the error, but the first argument needs to be a regular expression, not a string. I don't see the reason for the error, maybe it's an unmatched bracket on the previous line.

Comment: I can't copy and paste from a screenshot, so I can't be sure if I'm reading it correctly.

Comment: Output = Output.replaceAll("(?<!\\/|[0-9])[0-9]{5,}", match => "x".repeat(match.length));

Comment: I get no error when I paste that into the console.

Comment: This platform does not support //g without quotes for regex :(

Comment: All right, maybe I need to contact their support then, thanks anyway :D

Comment: You can use `new RegExp("...", "g")`